# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable while inserting TMDB data into the database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a simple code that takes data from TMDB API and saves it into the database but while doing this sometimes it throws TypeError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fill_data.py", line 63, in <module>
    collect_data(data)
  File "fill_data.py", line 31, in collect_data
    "genres": [[genre.get('name') for genre in data.get('genres')]],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is there any way to solve this?
I am using the links.csv file which is provided by the MovieLens dataset here is the link https://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-25m.zip

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from tqdm import tqdm
import requests

links_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'management/dataset/links.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(links_path)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="password",
    database="database",
    port=3306
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()


def collect_data(tmdbid_df):
    for i in tqdm(tmdbid_df['tmdbId']):
        reponse = requests.get(f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{i}?api_key=tmdb_api_key')
        data = reponse.json()
        d = {"id": [data.get('id')],
             "imdb_id": [data.get('imdb_id')],
             "original_language": [data.get('original_language')],
             "original_title": [data.get('original_title')],
             "overview": [data.get('overview')],
             "genres": [[genre.get('name') for genre in data.get('genres')]],
             "popularity": [data.get('popularity')],
             "poster_path": [data.get('poster_path')],
             "production_company_name": [[company.get('name') for company in data.get('production_companies')]],
             "production_company_poster": [[company.get('logo_path') for company in data.get(
                 'production_companies')]],
             "vote_average": [data.get('vote_average')],
             "vote_count": [data.get('vote_count')],
             "revenue": [data.get('revenue')],
             "release_date": [data.get('release_date')],
             "adult": [data.get('adult')],
             "budget": [data.get('budget')],
             "spoken_languages": [[language.get('name') for language in data.get('spoken_languages')]],
             "status": [data.get('status')],
             "runtime": [data.get('runtime')]
             }
        sql = "INSERT INTO movies_movie_collected (tmdb_id, imdb_id,  " \
              "original_title, original_language, overview, genres, popularity, poster_path, production_company_name," \
              " production_company_poster, vote_average, vote_count, revenue, release_date, adult, budget, " \
              "spoken_languages, status, runtime) " \
              "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = ( 
        d['id'][0], d['imdb_id'][0], str(d['original_title'][0]), str(d['original_language'][0]), str(d['overview'][0]),
        str(d['genres'][0]), d['popularity'][0], d['poster_path'][0], str(d['production_company_name'][0]),
        str(d['production_company_poster'][0]), d['vote_average'][0], d['vote_count'][0], d['revenue'][0],
        d['release_date'][0], d['adult'][0], d['budget'][0], str(d['spoken_languages'][0]), d['status'][0],
        d['runtime'][0])
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()


collect_data(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to iterate a over a missing value. If you only need to ignore missing data and want to avoid a lot of ifs you can use .get() method default value as follows:

```
# instead of
"genres": [[genre.get('name') for genre in data.get('genres')]]

# use
"genres": [[genre.get('name') for genre in data.get('genres', [])]]
```

So, when your "genres" key is missing from your data, the get method will return an empty list which is a valid iterable.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now. I was stuck on this for hours I really appreciate your help.